# Indy IMAPClient UIDRetrieveAllEnvelopes not getting other character set properly

Tags: delphi, unicode, indy, utf

Using: Delphi XE2, Windows 8 with US-English as default language

I am writing an email client with Delphi. I'm using TIdIMAP4 to connect to a GMail mailbox via IMAP and getting the message list like this:

```
  var
   MessageList: TIdMessageCollection;
  begin
   IMAPClnt.SelectMailBox('INBOX');
   IMAPClnt.UIDRetrieveAllEnvelopes(IMAPClnt.MessageList);
```

Then I'm retrieving the message subjects like this:

```
  var
   IdMsg: TIdMessage;
   s: String
  begin
   for c := 0 to FIMAPClnt.MessageList.Count - 1 do
    begin
     IdMsg := FIMAPClnt.MessageList[c];
     s :=  IdMsg.Subject;
```

However, if the message subject is in a different language (say, Hebrew) then the message subjects are not displayed properly (see attached image) even on a computer with Hebrew set as the default Windows language.

How can I correct the code to ensure that it works properly, retrieving the language in the correct Unicode characters?

Screen capture:
[image]

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email headers in your screenshot have been encoded per [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) ("MIME Part Three: Message Header Extensions for Non-ASCII Text").  `TIdIMAP4.UIDRetrieveAllEnvelopes()` captures and stores the raw data and does not automatically decode it.  You can use the various `Decode...()` functions in the `IdCoderHeaader.pas` unit to decode the headers manually, eg:

```
uses
  ..., IdCoderHeader;

var
  IdMsg: TIdMessage;
  s: String
begin
  ...
  for c := 0 to FIMAPClnt.MessageList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    IdMsg := FIMAPClnt.MessageList[c];
    IdMsg.Subject := DecodeHeader(IdMsg.Subject);
    DecodeAddresses(IdMsg.FromList);
    DecodeAddress(IdMsg.Sender);
    DecodeAddresses(IdMsg.ReplyTo);
    DecodeAddresses(IdMsg.Recipients);
    DecodeAddresses(IdMsg.CCList);
    DecodeAddresses(IdMsg.BccList);
    ...
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: FYI when I went to implement this, I discovered that DecodeAddresses requires two parameters (it's possible this is a change in the API since this answer was posted?), so I ended up changing the DecodeAddresses lines similar to the following: `DecodeAddresses(IdMsg.FromList.EMailAddresses, IdMsg.FromList);`

Comment: I would not suggest that approach. When you read from the `EmailAddresses` property, you are actually generating a new string value, which may be different than the original. Since `TIdIMAP` has already parsed the original string and split it up into `FromList`, it would be better to simply loop through the items of `FromList` and decode them individually as needed.

Comment: Looking back through Indy's history, there has never been a 1-parameter version of `DecodeAddresses()`, it has always been a 2-parameter function. I don't remember where I got the 1-parameter version from.